# Umbraco Log Error Failed to load Xml from file

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I get lots of Errors in my Umbraco 7.2.6 log file. And sometimes the CMS is broken, needs to restart IIS or browser. All errors are somethings with the load or save XML Lock or Thread aborted. I use the default Umbraco config on a simple shared hosting environment.

But It often works well. (so no file permission or somethings I expect)

What is wrong?

```
2015-07-07 09:45:02,833 [10] INFO  umbraco.BusinessLogic.Log - [T15/D3] Log scrubbed.  Removed all items older than 2015-05-08 09:45:02
2015-07-07 09:45:40,726 [10] ERROR umbraco.content - [T8/D3] Failed to load Xml from file.
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at Umbraco.Core.AsyncLock.Lock(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at umbraco.content.EnsureFileLock()
   at umbraco.content.LoadXmlFromFile()
2015-07-07 09:45:40,741 [10] ERROR Umbraco.Web.WebServices.ScheduledPublishController - [T55/D3] Error executing scheduled task
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at umbraco.content.LoadXmlFromFile()
   at umbraco.content.LoadXmlLocked(SafeXmlReaderWriter safeXml, Boolean& registerXmlChange)
   at umbraco.content..ctor()
   at umbraco.content.<.cctor>b__17()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Umbraco.Web.WebServices.ScheduledPublishController.Index()
2015-07-07 09:45:40,757 [10] ERROR Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.ScheduledPublishing - [T7/D3] An error occurred with the scheduled publishing. The base url used in the request was: http://acc.xxxxxxx.nl:80/umbraco/, see http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Config-files/umbracoSettings/#ScheduledTasks documentation for details on setting a baseUrl if this is in error
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(String address, String data)
   at Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.ScheduledPublishing.PerformRun()
2015-07-07 09:46:14,905 [10] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T19/D3] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.IParameterEditor

2015-07-07 12:55:10,801 [17] ERROR umbraco.content - [T18/D11] Failed to save Xml to file.
System.TimeoutException: Failed to enter the lock within timeout.
   at Umbraco.Core.AsyncLock.Lock(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at umbraco.content.EnsureFileLock()
   at umbraco.content.<SaveXmlToFileAsync>d__d.MoveNext()

2015-07-07 14:03:09,702 [9] ERROR umbraco.content - [T7/D3] Failed to load Xml from file.
System.TimeoutException: Failed to enter the lock within timeout.
   at Umbraco.Core.AsyncLock.Lock(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at umbraco.content.EnsureFileLock()
   at umbraco.content.LoadXmlFromFile()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6802
it is fixed in the Umbraco v7.2.8 release.